# How to get the class name of a preceding div element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing a new design for which I need to get the name of the class of a div element above another div element.

Like this:

```
<div class="random name a"></div>
<div class="the name of this class depends on the name of the class above this div"></div>
```

Is there any way of knowing this with jQuery? I been looking around but couldn't find any clue yet.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you had an id you could have used prev().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use .prev for this - http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
$('div.the').prev().attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the class from the previous element:

```
$(this).prev().attr("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).addClass($(this).prev('div').attr('class'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>

var prevDivClass = $('.div2').prev().attr('class'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still don't understand how I could not find the info!

Comment: What do you mean? I just retested in FF. It prints 'div1' if I say alert('prevDivClass='+prevDivClass); That is what you needed, right?

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I mean that I don't understand my I couldn't find it on google as I looked for it before posting the question. Thanks again!